# Overiding Theme Responsiveness

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I used a theme with a slider called flexslider to make the "Who's Using NameCoach"
https://www.name-coach.com/ (box tiles section with a list of users)

The theme seems to inherently have some sort of responsiveness feature in it.
However if I adjust the window width to lets say that of a mobile screen users size these tiles get so small that the users cant even see it.

Was wondering if anyone knows of any overiding css effect such as setting
when window => max width: 450px;
The tiles grow bigger and show lets say 4 entries rather than all 12 in a very small size.

Thanks!

Comment: That's what you are looking for: [CSS Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this maybe?

```
@media (max-width : 450px) {
  .flexslider .slides>li { width: 120px !important; }

}
```